# Adding ArcGIS Server services or ArcSDE datasets to Tilemill?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, tilemill

Our web design department wants to use mapbox/tilemill to create webmaps for our public websites, but all our data is made available through ArcGIS-server or ArcSDE. Is there some way to use these directly in tilemill, maybe through OGR, or serverside script thats converts ArcGIS-services into geojson? 
I would prefer not set up a parallel storage in shapefile if I don't have to.

Extra caveat: our designers are hardcore Mac-users.

Answer (score 1):

one possible option is to use something like TileMill Connect, nearly everything you can see in Mxd files can be viewed in TileMill. Since it requires ArcGIS, Windows only.

http://get.arc2earth.com/help/sync/tilemill

http://mapbox.com/blog/announcing-arc2earth-sync/

Comment: I will check this out maybe I can use this tool to provide them templates or something.

Comment: that might get you started but if the problem is direct access to SDE (instead of an intermediary format/file), you'll need to be running Sync locally to stream the data into TileMill. btw, I'm affiliated with Arc2Earth

Comment: so running sync of a server won't work for the fake postgis service ?

Comment: right, Sync/TileMill Connect will only run on a Windows machine and serve locally. You could take the Carto it creates and move it to the Mac machines but then you would not have access to the SDE data (TileMill Connect does two things: create the Carto and then stream data from Mxds)